# SOLR order by field_in_set like mysql

Tags: mysql, solr

I have the following result from Solr.

```
{
  "responseHeader": {
    "status": 0,
    "QTime": 1,
    "params": {
      "sort": "ID DESC",
      "indent": "true",
      "q": "*",
      "_": "1462775459580",
      "wt": "json"
    }
  },
  "response": {
    "numFound": 10,
    "start": 0,
    "docs": [
      {
        "Name": "Info",
        "AddedOn": "2016-04-19 00:46:10.0",
        "BusinessName": "InfoSeffcon",
        "ID": "389",
        "LatLongCombined": "37.5641425,-122.00417900000002",
        "_version_": 1533659952448536600
      },
      {
        "Name": "QA 1 SP",
        "AddedOn": "2016-03-20 22:02:16.0",
        "ID": "344",
        "LatLongCombined": "40.71364869999999,-74.00871259999997",
        "_version_": 1533659952447488000
      }
```

}

How can I apply the order by field_in_set to the SOLR query.

Basically I want to get results by the ID field.

eg. If I specify ID: 344 then the record with 344 should come first and then other records.

I should get the following result:

```
{
  "responseHeader": {
    "status": 0,
    "QTime": 1,
    "params": {
      "sort": "ID DESC",
      "indent": "true",
      "q": "*",
      "_": "1462775459580",
      "wt": "json"
    }
  },
  "response": {
    "numFound": 10,
    "start": 0,
    "docs": [
    {
        "Name": "QA 1 SP",
        "AddedOn": "2016-03-20 22:02:16.0",
        "ID": "344",
        "LatLongCombined": "40.71364869999999,-74.00871259999997",
        "_version_": 1533659952447488000
      },
      {
        "Name": "Info",
        "AddedOn": "2016-04-19 00:46:10.0",
        "BusinessName": "InfoSeffcon",
        "ID": "389",
        "LatLongCombined": "37.5641425,-122.00417900000002",
        "_version_": 1533659952448536600
      }
}
```

How can I achieve this using SOLR. I am pretty new to SOLR can anyone please help!

Answer (score 0):

You can do the sorting with the field.

`id asc` : sort in ascending order of the "id" field

`id desc` : sort in descending order of the "id" field

[Solr Docs](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/CommonQueryParameters#sort) : Sorting can be done on the `"score"` of the document, or on any `multiValued="false" indexed="true"` field provided that field is either non-tokenized (ie: has no `Analyzer`) or uses an Analyzer that only produces a single Term (ie: uses the `KeywordTokenizer`)

Comment: I want the ID's which I specify should come first and others records after that. Is this possible with what you have provided?

Comment: Can you please give me an example of it. I am beginner in SOLR.